# How to determine the IRQ number for a USB device?

Tags: linux, usb, driver, interrupt, irq

I am new to driver development. However, I purchased an OSR USB FX2 Learning Kit, which comes with sample codes for Windows kernel/user mode driver. However, I am writing the driver in Linux (Ubuntu 12). I have successfully been able to send control commands and receive the return of control commands from the device. I also have been able to successfully send and read data over the BULK OUT/IN endpoints the device supports.

There is only one more experiment I have yet to complete. The device has the following endpoints:

```
1. BULK (OUT) --> Address 0x06
2. BULK (IN)  --> Address 0x88
3. INTERRUPT (IN) --> Address 0x81
```

I am unable to figure out how to find the **IRQ number** for the **INTERRUPT (IN)** endpoint. I understand how to install an IRQ handler using:

```
int request_irq (unsigned int irq,
                 irq_handler_t handler,
                 unsigned long irqflags,
                 const char * devname,
                 void * dev_id);
```

and write the handler with the correct function prototype. However, I am wondering how I would find what IRQ line (IRQ number) the device is interrupting on? That is, how do I determine what the value of the argument **unsigned int irq** in the **request_irq** function above should be? I read through the book "Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition" how the IRQ number is determined for parallel ports. However, how does this work for USB and how would I go about probing or finding out what this number should be for the USB device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to deal with interrupts for writing a USB device driver, if you would like a good tutorial on it have a look at

http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/10/usb-drivers-in-linux-1/

which is an excellent starting point to learn how to write USB drivers;

If you have specific issues as you go along; post them we'll see how it goes :)

EDIT

you can use platform_get_irq or platform_get_irq_byname to get the irq for the device.

EDIT 2:

I also point you to http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch10.pdf for your viewing pleasure :-) Shows you how to retrieve IRQs assigned to devices.

Comment: The link you posted of the "pen driver" has only two endpoints: BULK IN/OUT. So it makes sense why that article does not address interrupts. However, my device has three endpoints: BULK IN/OUT and an INTERRUPT IN. Therefore, the device can send an interrupt to the host when a switch is flipped from on/off (vice-versa). How else can I detect when the user has flipped the switch? I know I can continuously poll for changes to the switches configuration (relative to the last recorded configuration value), however that does not seem to be the best way to go about it.

Comment: I believe you call platform_get_irq() and platform_get_irq_byname() after you have installed an IRQ handler using request_irq(). The devname and dev_id you provide to request_irq() become the arguments to platform_get_irq() and platform_get_irq_byname(), respectively. However my issue is determining what IRQ the device will interrupt on to install the IRQ Handler. Also, To confirm this, I tried using both functions and received "-6" as a return value, error code -6 is -ENXIO, which means "No such device or address", which makes sense since the IRQ handler was not yet created.

Comment: Hmm I briefly read this chapter before. Let me take another look at it and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: So I believe you were sort of right in your first reply. I tried creating an IRQ handler on all available IRQ lines (trial/error) and was unable to find a single one that the OSR FX2 USB device interrupts on. However, I did find an open source implementation on github (see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/osrfx2/). I noticed that they poll the interrupt endpoint as opposed to creating an IRQ handler over a particular line. Therefore, the USB device uses a sort of "virtual" interrupt line (only words that come to mind to describe it). So everything happens on the endpoints. Makes sense! Thanks.

Comment: P.S. When I said "I know I can continuously poll for changes to the switches configuration ... however that does not seem to be the best way to go about it" in my first comment, what I meant was: I would create a thread that continuously sends a CONTROL (READ) command to the USB device requesting the current switch configurations. Then it would compare it to the last read configuration value, and if there was a change, then it would set a global variable to true. Another thread would change it to false upon processing. However, polling the interrupt endpoint makes much more sense.

Comment: USB interrupt transfers are not at all related to IRQs. Interrupt transfers are initiated by the host, so polling the interrupt endpoint is the best way to proceed.